# F# why is cast needed?

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# and working through this [article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds/#catamorphisms). In this article there is a sample of the following recursive type:

```
type Book = {title: string; price: decimal}

type ChocolateType = Dark | Milk | SeventyPercent
type Chocolate = {chocType: ChocolateType ; price: decimal}

type WrappingPaperStyle =
    | HappyBirthday
    | HappyHolidays
    | SolidColor

type Gift =
    | Book of Book
    | Chocolate of Chocolate
    | Wrapped of Gift * WrappingPaperStyle
    | Boxed of Gift
    | WithACard of Gift * message:string
```

Which is used in the following way:

```
let wolfHall = {title="Wolf Hall"; price=20m}

let birthdayPresent = WithACard (Wrapped (Book wolfHall, HappyBirthday), "Happy Birthday")
```

What I don't understand: Why do I need to cast `wolfHall` to a `Book`? The compiler should know that `wolfHall` is a `Book`, and therefore a `Gift`, based on the beforehand let-assignment.

Thanks

Comment: It's not a cast. It's creating a value of type `Gift` by calling one of its five constructors named `Book`. It happens to have the same name as the type `Book`, but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `Book` means two things:

1. It's the name of the record type with two fields, `title` and `price`.
2. It's one of the cases of the discriminated union `Gift`. This particular case is of type `Book` (the record type), and it's named `Book`. It doesn't have to be named the same, but it can be (and often is - the same is true of the next case, `Chocolate`).

So, you're not casting `wolfHall`. You're constructing an instance of `Gift`, using the particular case constructor which happens to be named the same as the type it wraps. The compiler knows the difference and usually when you're reading the code, you can tell the difference. But if it's confusing, you can certainly name that constructor something else.